# Amazon EC2 Instances seem to have different RDS Latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, latency

While load testing my application, found out that except one instance, all instances are very slow to access RDS.

Currently, I am using Classic ELB for multiple EC2 instances and they share only one RDS(PSQL 9.4.9). I found this error by running migrate at each different instance and realized that only one instance finished migration in 1 sec. Rest of them takes more than 3 secs. Also, RDS MultipleAZ is turned off.

Is there any suggestion to solve this latency difference among the instances?

Thank you

Comment: How do the instances connect to the RDS? By migrate, do you mean you are running something like a Django DB migration? Are the instances identical (size type AZ region)?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I meant Django migration. Also the configuration for the instances are all identical.